# Query on FOR UPDATE NOWAIT in case of FK in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, locking

I have a table `tab1 (t_id, status)` and table `tab2 (id, t_id, status)` where in `t_id.tab2` has Foreign Key reference to `tab1.t_id`.

Assume an Oracle session s1 acquires `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` lock on a record in `tab1` with `t_id=123`.

While `NOWAIT` lock is still held by s1 on `tab1`, can another session s2 update record in `tab2` with `tab2.t_id=123` (FK)?

Comment: Yes, they are independent. Take into account that you could even change the t_id field and make it point to another record.

Comment: Thanks for quick response pablomatico. I'll give it a try

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Is `t_id` in `tab2` indexed?  And are you updating the `t_id` in the child table or some other attribute of the row?  Life gets a bit stickier if you're using an old version of Oracle, your foreign keys aren't indexed, and you're trying to update the `t_id` in `tab2`.

Comment: Oracle 11g version.
yes t_id is indexed in tab2. I'm trying to update some other attribute of the row in tab2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, the row lock issued with the *locking read* (`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`) statement does not propagate to the child table where the `FOREIGN KEY` is declared.

Here's an example that demonstrates this:

```
-- Set up schema
CREATE TABLE tab1 (t_id NUMBER(10), status VARCHAR2(10), PRIMARY KEY (t_id));
CREATE TABLE tab2 (id NUMBER(10), t_id NUMBER(10), status VARCHAR2(10), 
                  PRIMARY KEY (id),
                  CONSTRAINT fk_tab1 FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES tab1 (t_id));
INSERT INTO tab1 (t_id, status) VALUES (123, 'Status1');
INSERT INTO tab1 (t_id, status) VALUES (234, 'Status1');
INSERT INTO tab2 (id, t_id, status) VALUES (1, 123, 'Status2');
INSERT INTO tab2 (id, t_id, status) VALUES (2, 234, 'Status2');
COMMIT;
```

The following script, which uses the `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` pragma for issuing a new transaction, executes successfully (e.g. in Oracle SQLDeveloper):

```
SET autocommit 0;
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE t_id=123 FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  UPDATE tab1 SET status = 'Status2' WHERE t_id = 234;
  UPDATE tab2 SET t_id = 234, status = 'Status2' WHERE t_id = 123;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

So, it's possible to change other rows in `tab1` and also the foreign key column in `tab2` which points to the locked row in `tab1`.

As expected, trying to update the locked row:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE t_id=123 FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  UPDATE tab1 SET status = 'Status2' WHERE t_id = 123;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

... will fail with the error message:

```
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```